# How to move close button in fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I need to change the position of the close button in fancybox 2 script. Can't figure out how. Please help. 
http://squaretwo.ru/fancybox.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fancybox close button is managed by a css file(jquery.fancybox.css), so try changing it's properties(top and right) to get it where you want, here's my close button css:

```
.fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -18px;
    right: -18px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That how I do:

```
#fancybox-close {
    right: 20px !important;
    top: 12px !important;
}
```

Comment: there is not such selector in fancybox 2